# Calculate row width

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have built a small tool like phpmyadmin for Firebird (2.5.1) in PHP, and I'm running into a few problems.

Sometimes I'm dealing with large tables with a lot of columns, some are close to the 64K row width limit. Once I try to execute an ALTER TABLE query to add a column that exceeds this limit, PHP just locks up when I try to commit the query, never returning a response or error message. To avoid this, I want to calculate the current total row width of the table before attempting to add the new column.

For example, I have a table with 638 columns (nothing I can do about that), and I tried to add a VARCHAR column of 64 bytes (I know characters can take up multiple bytes, so I'm using bytes to avoid confusion). PHP freezes, and FlameRobin tells me on commit: `new record size of 65594 bytes` is too big. Then I started doing some calculations.

I use the following query to calculate the row width based on the reported sizes in Firebird:

```
SELECT
    SUM(f.rdb$field_length)
FROM
    rdb$relation_fields rf
LEFT JOIN
    rdb$fields f ON rf.rdb$field_source=f.rdb$field_name
WHERE
    UPPER(rf.rdb$relation_name)='MY_TABLE';
```

This gives me a grand total of **64721 bytes**.

That can't be right, because that gives me 815 bytes to spare, more than enough to add 64 bytes.

Then I read somewhere that VARCHAR fields store an additional 2 bytes for the length. Makes sense, so I incorporate this in my calculations. I have 333 VARCHAR fields in this table, so I add 666 bytes to get a total of **65387 bytes**, with 149 bytes to spare.

Again, this is still enough to store 64 bytes (no, wait, it's 66 bytes now)

Apparently, Firebird sees the current row width as 65528, and I wonder how this is determined. Are there other fields that have a small overhead as well? I can't figure it out, I hope someone out there has an answer :)

Comment: Please include the DDL of the table and the attempted addition of the column. IIRC, there are some internals that count towards the maximum width of a row, for example the null-value bitset, which with 638 columns will take 80 bytes (maybe a few more). I'm not 100% sure about this though. But seriously, 638 columns is way too much for any sane data model.

Comment: Not related to the question itself, but why are you still using 2.5.1, and not 2.5.7? Several security bugs have been fixed since 2.5.1.

Comment: 2.5.1 had a nasty index bug, to upgrade the server he would have to backup-restore all the databases

Comment: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/Firebird-Internals.pdf - While holds for FB2.5.x this is implementation detail that can change in future any moment. And I think it is very improbable that the server just freezes without reporting an error. Look into firebird.log - maybe you crash the server?